# Font size problem

Tags: macbook-pro

I accidentally hit command/underline and it made the print super tiny.  I tried doing command/z to go back and it didn't work.  I'm a 73 grandma and bit challenged technologically.  Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean in a 'text' or web scenario...

The standard controls for font/view resizing are
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>- [minus]</kbd>  (which is, in effect, command/underline)
to reduce the view/font
&
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>+ [plus]</kbd> 
to increase it.

You can change your 'zoom' level by hitting either of those until your view is to your satisfaction.